# Rendering Grafana inside django website using API Key

Tags: django, authentication, render, grafana

I’m attempting to pass an API token for a user to grafana from our own internal website so that the main gui renders in an iframe. We don’t want the users to have to log into grafana after they have logged into our site, so we are creating their users in grafana, building an API token and attaching that to the user for our website. When the user goes to the page that has the grafana iframe, we are sending an ajax get request with the token so grafana renders the main dashboards with the users information.

If we do just a standard iframe everything works fine and we render inside the frame. We can get to the login page and do everything we need to. When I add the token so we don’t need to authenticate nothing renders and I see no errors/logs on either grafana or the website. If I send an invalid token I see the expected “401 invalid Api key” error on both the website and the grafana logs. This is what I’m sending from the website…

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="container">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$.ajax({
    url: "{{url}}",
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer {{token}}');
    },
    success: function(r) { 
        $('#container').html(r);
    }
});
</script>
```

With the above nothing happens, I get no errors or logs. If I keep everything else the same and just adjust the token to make it invalid, grafana says it is invalid, so I know it is making it to the server. Why is nothing coming back to be rendered?

Thanks!

Comment: just to be sure, if you use your browser network console, and inspect the request that is sent to Grafana, are the URl and token matching what you expect?

Comment: They are.  If I change the token I get an error from the grafana server saying the token is incorrect.  So it is hitting the grafana server and validating, just either nothing is being returned or I'm not able to render it.

Comment: I'm going to end this question as further research leads me to believe grafana doesn't support requests the way I am sending them.

Answer (score 0):

That' s an Error in Grafana-API, the generated API-Key. Use a Key that is generated inside Grafana